# How to force Scala to not use origin of type aliases?

Tags: scala

I created `type MyString = String`.

Now I want my function to accept only my `MyString`, not `String`, latter should not compile at all.

`def myFunc(s: MyString) = println(s)` accepts both `String` and `MyString` args:

```
scala> type MyString = String
defined type alias MyString

scala> def myFunc(s: MyString) = println(s)
myFunc: (s: MyString)Unit

scala> val s1: MyString = "aaa"
s1: MyString = aaa

scala> myFunc(s1)
aaa

scala> val s2: String = "aaa"
s2: String = aaa

scala> myFunc(s2)
aaa

scala> trait MyString extends String
<console>:10: error: illegal inheritance from final class String
       trait MyString extends String
                              ^

scala> s1
res7: MyString = aaa

scala> s2
res8: String = aaa

scala> s1 == s2
res9: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with

```
type MyString = String
```

you are stating that type `MyString` *is* `String`, so they will be useable (largely) interchangeably within the scope where they are both defined.

To enforce usage of `MyString` over `String`, you can define it as a wrapper class instead:

```
case class MyString(value: String) extends AnyVal
```

Note: extending `AnyVal` prevents an extra class being instantiated at runtime - see [Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) for more info.

You get the restriction on function parameter values you want this way, although it does come at the cost of needing to explicitly instantiate instances of your new type:

```
scala> val s1: MyString = MyString("aaa")
s1: MyString = aaa

scala> myFunc(s1)
aaa

scala> val s2: String = "aaa"
s2: String = aaa

scala> myFunc(s2)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: MyString
              myFunc(s2)
                     ^
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I want. Wrappers like this are some kind of crutch. I want `MyString` to be a `String` with some extra restrictions (say, only 10 characters), whereas your suggestion wont allow to use `MyString` in functions that except `String`. That's why I added line with `extends`, it would work if String wasn't final.

Comment: @user2317480 Yes, there are limits to how well this matches your intentions. If you need `MyString` to be accepted anywhere a `String` parameter is expected, though, you could add an implicit conversion from `MyString` to `String`, eg: `implicit def mine2str(myStr: MyString): String = myStr.value`.

Comment: Main disadvantage of your approach is that I (as a developer) have to remember that string should have 10 characters. I'd like to make compiler remember it for me. Assert also is not the solution, since it's runtime. Probably some type-level magic a-la shapeless required. Seems like I should edit my question.

Comment: However, with assertion, your suggestion is good enough for my purposes, so I accept the answer. Two disadvantages (runtime check and overhead for the wrapper) are not so risky.

Comment: Such a check (having a length of 10 characters) could only possibly be checked at compile time against constant String values.

Comment: I edited my answer to note that by extending `AnyVal`, the runtime allocation of space for the wrapper class (and consequent un/boxing) can be avoided.

Comment: Unfortunately, value classes do not allow asserts inside.

Comment: Yes, the assert should go into `MyString.apply`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use [tagged types](http://etorreborre.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html):

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

trait String10CharsTag

type String10Chars = String @@ String10CharsTag

def string10Chars(s: String) = 
  if (s.length == 10) Some(s.asInstanceOf[String10Chars]) else None
```

Note that `String10Chars` is a subtype of `String`, so it can be used as an argument to methods taking `String`. It's also always represented just as `String` at runtime (AFAIK, but I don't see how it could *not* be), while value classes can still be instantiated in some circumstances.

Comment: Could you please edit '==' to single '=' in type alias definition? SO says that edit should have at least 6 characters, so I cannot do it myself. About the answer itself: very interesting technique, never seen it before, and I need some time to investigate it.